# python2 libraries not found when building opencv on Mac OS X 10.11.4

Tags: python, opencv, build, cmake, osx-elcapitan

I'm following the instructions [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) to install opencv on my mac machine running El Capitan 10.11.4.

According to Step#8 in the link, I run the cmake command as follows:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
-D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
-D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
-D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules/ ..
```

It generated the build files but cannot find the python2 libraries as shown below:

[image]

And, pyhton2 shows up in the `Unavailable` list rather than the `To be built` list as shown below:

[image]

I don't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Please help!

Comment: Aren't python2 and its libraries should be of the same version? You have python2 **executable** of version **2.7.10**, but according to path, **libraries** are for version **2.7.11**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Any idea how to fix it?